# Does manually unlocking power door locks damage them?

Tags: door, central-locking

I have a friend who insists that manually unlocking a door that has power locks damages the mechanism, and I disagree.

Is there any truth to this belief?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Realistically, if they weren't meant to be used manually, they wouldn't be there.

Answer (score 1):

Hardware-wise, the linear actuator for the power lock has a grooved rod that locks and unlocks the door by moving the lever that you use to lock the door with.  When you use your power lock, you are actually causing more wear because you are also using the electric motor.